# issues with app.yaml and in the design of the server

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, yaml

I need to impl a few basic features in this server:

1. display a nice main screen(html) with < select > widget and 2 buttons(one to choose a image from hd to upload and another to send) + TextEditBox for typing a msg
2. when the user clicks 'send' - take the users choice from the select widget and
3. the image will be uploaded

I have managed to implement all of it separately, now when I come to make it all work together I have a problem with app.yaml url paths due to a bad design.

app.yaml looks like:

```
runtime: python    

handlers:
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/(.*)

- url: /.*
  script: kserver.py
```

kserver.py:

```
class StartPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        select_items = db.GqlQuery( "SELECT * FROM Registration" )
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.out.write(template.render("tst.html", {'select_items': select_items}))

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        image = self.request.get("img")
        photo = Photo()
        photo.imageblob = db.Blob(image)
        photo.put()
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

class DownloadImage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        photo= db.get(self.request.get("photo_id"))
        if photo:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/jpeg"
            self.response.out.write(photo.imageblob)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Image not available")

class Sender(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        ...
        ...
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'     # reply with 200 OK
        self.response.set_status( 200,"OK" )
        ...
        ...

class TokenService(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.set_status( 200,"Registration accepted" )
        ...

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', StartPage),
                                      ('/sender',Sender),
                                      ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                                      ('/i', DownloadImage),
                                      ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),
                                      ('/token',TokenService)],
                                      debug=True)
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the tst.html :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select name="accountName">
            <option value=\"ALL\">ALL</option>
            {% for item in select_items %}
        <option value="{{ item.accountName }}">{{ item.accountName }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <form action="sender" method="POST">
            <input  type="text" id="TextEditBox_1">
            <input  type="submit" name="submit">
            <input  type="file" name="img" id="Choose_file">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

note, Identation is fine, its only parts of code.

in the project, i have a images directory that contains app.ico and backgroung image (statics)

Okay, now the problem is i get in GAE logs :

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: images/token
Static file referenced by handler not found: images/sender
```

this is not intended. it should be in '/' i think

and

```
"/token 404 48ms 0kb            No handlers matched this URL."
```

in addition, when clicking on "send" it redirects me to a new page with :

```
The requested URL /sender was not found on this server.
```

this /token is a POST coming from outside to register to the server - the server than store registrations in db. when "send" button pressed ,it should use this db.register tokens.

any comments on the subject is most welcome. thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The patterns in your app.yaml are too general:

```
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/(.*)
```

will match just about anything, so the requests that are meant to be handled by code never get there.  Try something like this:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
```

which will handle only files that end with gif, png or jpg.

Answer (score 4):

Your first handler matches anything with at least one character after the first slash; you'll need to use a url like /images/.* or only match files ending in `(jpg|gif|png|ico)`, e.g.